# 3DS Max equivalent to vertex weight painting

Tags: 3d-meshes, models, rigging

I'm working in 3ds max on models for an Iphone game project and finding that using the Physique modifier is to general for rigging. When working with so few vertices I want to be able to directly tell how much weight a bone should have on a specific vertex.

Is there a 3ds max equivalent to the Softimage XSI vertex weight painting? As this would be perfect for this job.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you want to use Skin not Physique. It's mainly in there for backward compatibility with character studio from years ago.

Max: [Rigging tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/3dsmaxhowtos#p/c/54DFAAA0320637A6)

Comment: Thanks, the artist I worked under obviously didn't keep up with standards